# Replacement for the retired SpaDES package

Tags: r, spatial

I recently started working with Spatial packages. I am trying to replicate the code for a recently published paper that uses the "[SpaDES](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SpaDES/index.html)" package. But this package has been archived since 2022-11-09.

What is a replacement for this retired package?

Comment: You could download the latest version from the archive [link](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SpaDES/) and install

Comment: It is likely not 'retired' but has failed to respond to CRAN about some something, and archiving is how CRAN gets pkg dev's attention. You could, in a terminal, `git clone https://github.com/PredictiveEcology/SpaDES.git`, R CMD build SpaDES. This will make a tar.gz (assuming linux), then R CMD INSTALL SpaDES...tar.gz. With Windows you'll need `RTools` installed. Several different options are suggested [SpaDES - github](https://github.com/PredictiveEcology/SpaDES).

Comment: @Cris your solution worked. Thank you so much. I typed the following lines in my Terminal on mac:                                         git clone https://github.com/PredictiveEcology/SpaDES.git
R CMD build SpaDES 
 R CMD INSTALL SpaDES_2.0.9.tar.gz